# Are the words "of earth" an adjective?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality

For example, I would like to say: The world is both of earth and {another adjective}. 
Since earth is a noun it didn't seem right. However, I was wondering if adding the 'of' would make it an adjective. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not an adjective: "adjective" is a class of word, not of grammatical construct.

It could be an adjectival phrase, but I wouldn't call it that, as it can replace an adjective only in a limited number of positions (**The of earth world* is not grammatical, for example).

I would call it a PP (prepositional phrase); but that does not mean that it cannot be coordinated with another kind of modifier, such as an adjective. To pluck an example from the air, if you search for "serious and in earnest", you will find plenty of examples.

Comment: I see somebody has downvoted without comment. I wonder who.

Answer (score -2):

In that context, it's nominal, not adjectival.  Prepositional phrases are modifying phrases and can be adjectival, adverbial or nominal.  In this case, "of earth" is a prepositional phrase that appears after the verb "be" is employed and so is nominal.

http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/prepositions/prepositional-phrases.html

Comment: I don't see this. In this use it is modifying a NP, so (according to that classification) it is adjectival. Whether or not it _can_ follow "be" is not diagnostic: the article you linked to gives _next to the telephone_ as a PP that is adjectival, and it can follow "is".

Comment: No, that's not what my source says.  You clearly didn't read carefully enough, probably because you don't like being wrong.  Because of that, you gave a right answer a down vote.  Congratulations on preferring to mislead people over admitting you're wrong.  What is it they say?  Oh, that's right: "Deny till ya die!"

Comment: I did not downvote, @Billy.  Congratulations on leaping to conclusions. I have disputed your claim that _of earth_ is nominal. I do not see how your source asserts that it is.